# non-default colorschemes can't be loaded; setting them manually after startup works

Tags: colorscheme, neovim, startup

Currently, I use [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) for managing plugins and [vim-colorschemes](https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes) for my  colorschemes - which doesn't work.

**Approach 1:**

in my init.vim:

```
Plug 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
[...]
syntax on
colorscheme babymate256
set background=dark
```

Putting those colorscheme settings at the end of my init.vim(=after my mappings), works. Putting those before my mappings (but after `filetype plugin`
and that) doesn't. That doesn't make much sense to me, but as neovim supports asynchron execution, that may be the cause.

Putting `set runtimepath+=~/.dotfiles/nvim/plugged/vim-colorschemes/colors` before those colorscheme settings doesn't work either.

**Approach 2:**

Putting all colorschemes from `nvim/plugged/vim-colorschemes/colors` into `nvim/colors/` doesn't change anything.

Of course, i can set my colorscheme manually after nvim has started.

- I thought of using just an if structure for setting the colorscheme, but i don't know what i could test, as the colorscheme set doesn't provide any variables.
- why does the manual configuration using nvim/color doesn't work?
- Do you have suggestions on how to manage colorschemes?

**EDIT:** I don't like setting it at the end of my file, as it destroys my file structure.

Comment: Your default colorscheme seems to be babymate256. When you say it doesn't work, which colorscheme is loaded instead ? Could you provide the content of a log file `vim --startuptime log` to see which file sets up the colorscheme ? You can access the name of your current colorscheme through the global variable `g:colors_name` and load the colorscheme manually with the following command : `execute "colorscheme " . g:colors_name`

Comment: [log](http://paste.debian.net/334635/)
 Instead of babymate256, it has loaded the default one. Did you mean that?

Comment: @toogley Maybe I missed it, but I can't find the name of your default colorscheme in your log (it should be in a `colors` folder and the only one I see is `babymate256`). What's the name of your default colorscheme when you type `:colo` ? Another thing you could do to start investigating : type `:hi`, it will display all the highlight groups currently set. Find the name of one whose colors are not the ones you want (let's say for example `StatusLine`). Then type `:verb hi StatusLine` to discover which file last set the status line highlight group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although, i haven't found out what exactly was the problem or how i could solve it in the expected way (just placing colorscheme babymate256 in my config as everyone else does)

**=>** i now use just `autocmd VimEnter * colorscheme babymate256`
(which is not as fine as without an autocmd, but it doesn't disorganize up my config structure.)

Btw: Additionally, i just haven't found the exact name of my default colorscheme, ":colorscheme " had just printed "default"

---

**EDIT**
Afterwards, i solved a very similar problem by putting "set background=dark" *before* the colorscheme setting.

Comment: The `autocmd` is the only way I got it to work. But I don't understand the root issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but got it to work by putting the "colorscheme yourtheme" line after I've called the plugins.